# What is the proper time to recite the Aditya Hrudayam?

Tags: surya, stotra, adityas

What is the proper time for recitation of this stotra? Is it forbidden to listen/chant Aaditya Hrudayam after sunset?

Comment: The best time to do it is morning. If you can't do it in the morning then any time is preferable.It is always very useful and beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

As with most Hindu mantras, I would say during Brahmamuhurtha. Since it's related to the Sun, during sunrise and during solar eclipses would be good too.